# Visual basics help-Variables in for loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get the integers of "`num3`"(input from the user) and squaring each character and eventually see if its a "happy number"=1 or a "unhappy number" includes 4
For example, 19 is happy number 1^2+9^2=82 , 8^2+2^2=68,6^2+8^2=100, 1^2+0+0=1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim number, num2, total As Integer
    Dim num3 As String

    Console.Write("pick a number:")
    number = Console.ReadLine()
    num2 = 0
    num3 = Convert.ToString(number)


    Do Until total = 1 Or num2 = 4
        For Each num3 In num3.Substring(0, num3.Length)
            For counter = 1 To num3.Length And num3 = num3.Substring(0, num3.Length)
                num2 = num3 ^ 2
                total = total + num2
                Console.WriteLine(total)
            Next
            num3 = total


        Next

    Loop
    Console.ReadLine()

    If total = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("happy number")


    ElseIf num2 = 4 Then
        Console.WriteLine(number & "is a unhappy number")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Module

however i'm stuck whether "`num3`" replace itself from the for loop

Comment: You are doing For Each loop with "num3 = total", you are setting num3 to total in it.

Comment: Give an example of what the numbers are, what happens, and what you want to happen.

Comment: numbers are inputs from the user,. Im basically trying to get the integer the user gives e.g 19 then square each character so 1^2 +9^2 then add it together so 82 then take then take it apart again and square it until total becomes=1 but if the loop doesn't = 1 then it will continuously loop and 1 of the numbers that this cycle always includes the number 4. so thats why i have if num2=4. If total=1 its a happy number and if keeps cycling then its a unhappy number

Comment: So if value contains number 4, it will loop forever?

Comment: yes and if it does the output should show its a unhappy number

Comment: Alright, sounds interesting. I'll give it a try. Your code looks messy. And I did a quick check with calc, it's not that value can not contain 4, but that if result is 4 at any step it continues to loop forever.

Comment: ah sorry about that i'm quite new to coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I believe this should work:

```
    Dim InputNum As Integer = 45 'Your input number

    Dim TempNum As Integer = InputNum 'Here we hold number temporarily during steps 19>82....
    Do
        Dim SumTotal As Double = 0 'sum of numbers squares
        For Each number As Char In TempNum.ToString 
            SumTotal += Integer.Parse(number) ^ 2
        Next
        TempNum = CInt(SumTotal)
        Debug.Print(TempNum.ToString)
        'If result is 4 it will loop forever
        If SumTotal = 4 Then
            Console.WriteLine(InputNum & " is an unhappy number")
            Exit Do
        ElseIf SumTotal = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(InputNum & " is a happy number")
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Alright, if the code suits you don't forget to click the + and mark as answered.